# How to combine multiwords in a dfm?

Tags: r, quanteda

I created a corpus of 233 rows and 3 columns (Date, Title, Article) where the last column, *Article*, is text (so, I have 233 texts). The final aim is to apply topic models and, to do so, I need to convert my *corpus* into a *dfm*. Yet, I would like first to combine words into bigrams and trigrams to make the analysis more rigorous.

The problem is that when I use ***textstat_collocation*** or ***tokens_compound***, I am forced to tokenize the *corpus* and, in so doing, I lose the structure (233 by 4) that is crucial to apply topic models. In fact, once I apply those functions, I just get one row of bigrams and trigrams which is useless to me.

So my question is: do you know any other way to look for bigrams and trigrams in a dfm without necessarily tokenizing the corpus?

Or, in other words, what do you usually do to look for multiwords in a dfm?

Thanks a lot for your time!

Comment: Posting that as comment as I do not deem myself an expert in topic modeling but to the best of my knowledge the `topicmodels` package uses the Latent Dirichlet allocation model which takes into account word position in the given documents: I feel using/adding bigrams would not provide more information to the model.

Comment: It's not really clear what you want to achieve and why. Tokenizing a corpus and/or creating with metadata preserves all of the metadata (the document-level variables or _docvars_). The question about detecting multi-word expressions is entirely different, but you have not specified what sort of answer you are seeking.

Comment: Professor @KenBenoit I dropped you an email I guess it's easier to explain in person whenever have time I can come to your office, thanks and sorry if I wasn't clear

Comment: @JohnCoene It makes a difference if when you n topics the kth element of the topic M is **euro** or **euro area**, **budgetary** or *budgetary consolidation** and so on